# Working with PFX Certificates in Robot Framework. How to work with SOAP based API calls

Tags: robotframework, python-3.10, pfx

Recently I started to transform & migrate C# .NET based API automation to Robot Framework. These are SOAP based API calls. However though the end point loads fine in the browser, the basic structure of the function/methods in the browser are not loaded. This is because the requests should first be validated.
The validation happens using PFX certificates (new to me, never worked before). All the webservice functions can be tested and verified using ReadyAPI or SoapUI.

Now, if I want to do the same thing programmatically especially using Python, how can I do it?
I did plenty of tryouts using zeep, SoapLibrary, cryptography.hazmat.primitives, cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization etc. I am able to verify in some instances the public and private keys extracted from the pfx file or from the pem file (converted using OpenSSL).

All the above methods are error prone in which I get -
C4520000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1188:
OR
C4520000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS12
OR
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM Lib (_ssl.c:3999)')))
OR
Max retries exceeded with url: MyWebServiceEndPoint (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(399, '[SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:3900)')))

The certificate package PFX seems fine. Anyone knows a simple and clean way to API calls in Robot Framework with these certificates?

Thank you.

Tried using zeep, Session, OpenSSL.crypto and other Python packages/modules, but they did not work.